# Save a reader of a file in a database in Java

Tags: java, database, persistence, dao, bufferedreader

I have a Reader in Java:
And the reader `(Reader read)` is from a file with 1'000.000 of lines

And i need save each line in my database, i am reading the Reader like:

```
            int data = read.read();
            String line = "";


            while (data != -1) {
                char dataChar = (char) data;
                data = read.read();
                if (dataChar != '\n') {
                    line = line + dataChar;
                } else {
                    i++;
                    showline(line);
                    line = "";
                }
            }
```

Then i am calling my DAO for each line:

```
private static void showline(String line) {
    try {
        if (line.startsWith(prefix)) {
            line = line.substring(prefix.length());
        }
        ms = new Msisdn(Long.parseLong(line, 10), idList);
        ListDAO.createMsisdn(ms);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

And my DAO is:

```
public static void createMsisdn(Msisdn msisdn) {
    EntityManager e = DBManager.createEM();
    try {
        createMsisdn(msisdn, e);
    } finally {
        if (e != null) {
            e.close();
        }
    }

}

public static void createMsisdn(Msisdn msisdn, EntityManager em) {

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(msisdn);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

}
```

But my problem is that with a file with 1'000.000 lines it takes about 1 hour 30 minutes to complete. How can I make it faster?

(My main problem is call the DAO 1'000.000 of times because it is very slow, because the while is faster, without the call to the DAO the time is less than 1 minute, but with the call to the DAO the time is 2 hours)

Comment: If you can do it all within a single transaction, it might be faster or as a batch process

Comment: But how can i do in only one transaction in the upload of much rows in a database?

Comment: All your code demonstrates the basic idea.  You need some way to start, commit or rollback a transaction from your DAO

Answer (score 0):

Reading characters and appending them into a `String` one by one is incredibly inefficient. Using a `BufferedReader` to read lines of text is much better:

```
        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(read);
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            showline(line);
        }
```

This won't have a big effect in your case though: you are inserting each line in a separate transaction, and each transaction can take hundreds of milliseconds to complete. You should structure your code in a way that several lines could be inserted in a single transaction. For example you can read blocks of lines like this, but you'll have to change the `showlines` and `createMsisdn` methods so that they accept several at a time and process them in a single batch:

```
        final int TRANSACTION_SIZE = 500;
        int i = 0;
        String[] lines = new String[TRANSACTION_SIZE];
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(read);
        while ((lines[i] = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (i >= lines.length) { 
                showlines(lines, lines.length);
                i = 0;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }

        if (i > 0) showlines(lines, i);
```